# Chunk array by condition

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have array like this

```
[["Page_1", nil], ["ROW1", "one"], ["ROW2", "four"], ["ROW3", "seven"], ["End", nil], ["Page_2", nil], ["ROW4", "Ten"], ["ROW5", "thirteen"], ["End", nil], ["Page_4", nil], ["ROW6", "Sixteen"], ["ROW7", "Nineteen"], ["End", nil]]
```

I want to insert the inner array into another array If array consist of 'Page' and I have stop when the array has 'End',So the resultant array has to be

```
[
  [["Page_1", nil], ["ROW1", "one"], ["ROW2", "four"], ["ROW3", "seven"], ["End", nil]],
  [["Page_2", nil], ["ROW4", "Ten"], ["ROW5", "thirteen"], ["End", nil]], 
  [["Page_4", nil], ["ROW6", "Sixteen"], ["ROW7", "Nineteen"], ["End", nil]]
]
```

I tried to use the flip flop operator of ruby but since it's having more than one end, it's taking the entire array, so it doesn't work. Is there any other way I can achieve this in ruby?

Comment: Thinking in an iterative style, you want to 1) have an (empty) results variable 2) iterate over the array, 2a) memorizing when you are in an interesting area of the array 2b) by storing start (and end-position) and 2c) add the interesting areas to the result. What exactly goes wrong? Which methods in Array or Enumerable are interesting for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
your_array
  .chunk { |ary| ary.first.match?("Page") }
  .each_slice(2)
  .map { |group| group.flat_map(&:last) }
#=> [
#     [["Page_1", nil], ["ROW1", "one"], ["ROW2", "four"], ["ROW3", "seven"], ["End", nil]],
#     [["Page_2", nil], ["ROW4", "Ten"], ["ROW5", "thirteen"], ["End", nil]],
#     [["Page_4", nil], ["ROW6", "Sixteen"], ["ROW7", "Nineteen"], ["End", nil]]
#   ]
```

Comment: Chunk method, yes, I was expecting a predefined method something like this.Awesome dude! Actually `match?` method is not working for me, so I used `include?`, I am using Ruby 2.3.3. Is that the reason?

Comment: @Rajagopalan yes, I think `String#match?` was added around 2.4 (you should upgrade your version btw)

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition was correct: this is a good application for the [flip-flop](https://blog.newrelic.com/engineering/weird-ruby-part-3-fun-flip-flop-phenom/) operator. If `arr` is your array, you can write the following.

```
arr.slice_after { |f,_| true if f=='End' .. f=='End' }.to_a
  #=> [
  #     [["Page_1", nil], ["ROW1", "one"], ["ROW2", "four"],
  #      ["ROW3", "seven"], ["End", nil]],
  #     [["Page_2", nil], ["ROW4", "Ten"], ["ROW5", "thirteen"],
  #      ["End", nil]],
  #     [["Page_4", nil], ["ROW6", "Sixteen"], ["ROW7", "Nineteen"],
  #      ["End", nil]]
  #   ]
```

The flip-flop is turned ON when `f == 'End'`, causing `true` to be returned to the block, then, before the next element of the array is passed to the block, it checks the ending condition, `f == 'End'`, resulting in the flip-flop being turned OFF, causing 'false' to be returned to the block until `f == 'End'` is `true` for a subsequent element of the array.

Here's another way.

```
arr.each_with_object([[]]) do |pair,a|
  a[-1] << pair
  a << [] if pair.first == "End"
end.tap { |a| a.pop if a[-1].empty? }
```

Comment: I knew you would be coming up with different solution. I made a single mistake by giving page and end in flip flop operator. You came up by the right one. Brilliant, thank you.